# Installed Ubuntu with faulty RAM: do I need to reinstall?

Tags: installation, ram

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Sony Viao vpceb3e1e. Everything works fine till I reach a certain amount of memory, then all the apps crash. I found out it was due to faulty RAM. I used Memtest86+ to figure out the problem and only 1 of my RAM sticks is broken. I'm now only using the non-broken one.

Since I installed Ubuntu with the faulty RAM to start off with (I'm 100% sure it was broken when I installed it since it was a recurring issue for 6 months), should I do a full reinstall?

Or, is there a way to check the consistency of my system to see if there have been errors written to the disk? and a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend a reinstall, or at least a full integrity check of installed files. It's quite possible that some of the files were corrupted during installation.

You can check the integrity of files that are provided by a package with the following command:

```
cd /
md5sum -c /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.md5sums | grep -v 'OK$'
```

If some packages turn out to contain corrupted files, you can reinstall them with `sudo apt-get --reinstall install PACKAGENAME`.

Beware that this only checks files that are directly provided by packages, not configuration files that were modified locally, binary files that were compiled locally, your own data, etc.

Comment: As it turns out after running the code I have many many errors. Will probably be faster to reinstall then to try fix them 1 by 1. Thanks